# Updateing from MvvmCross.HotTuna.Droid.FullFragging to MvvmCross.Droid.FullFragging -> MvxFragment can not be resolved

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

Since `MvvmCross.HotTuna.Droid.FullFragging` is pointed out as Deprecated I updated to `MvvmCross.Droid.FullFragging` as recomanded.

Althoug my projects references show `MvvmCross.Droid.FullFragging`, the `MvxFragment` can not be resolved.

What is it, I am doing wrong?

Comment: The namespace is `MvvmCross.Droid.FullFragging.Fragments`. Did you add the correct using?

Comment: `MvxFragment` is also an attribute. If you add a reference to that it won't work.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?

Comment: Unfortunately not.